# Does mclapply wait if there are dependents on output?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mclapply

I have the following psuedocode situation:

`results1 <- mclapply(stuff, myfunc1())
results2 <- mclapply(morestuff, myfunc2())
finalresults <- mclapply(results1, results2)`

Is the package smart enough to wait until all the threads spawned by `results1` and `results2` are completed before trying to calculate `finalResults`? If not, is there a flag I can put in so that it doesn't move forward until `results1` is fully complete? Etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the 2nd and 3rd lines will not be executed until the previous ones complete.